# copying the rows one below another checking on the last filled column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet List. I want the contents of list to be transferred to my sheet Evaluation. But my evaluation sheet, already consist of the previous evaluation. I want the new rows just below the old ones. Can some one help how I can achieve this ?

I have the below code with me, which is a copy paste functionality.

```
Sub lastweekctt()
Worksheets("List").Range("A4:W1000").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Evaluation").Range("A5")
End Sub
```

I have my header in row 4 in both the sheets.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get last blank row:

```
Sub lastweekctt()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    'get last row
    LastRow = Worksheets("Evaluation").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("List").Range("A4:W1000").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Evaluation").Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It would be best to also qualify your Rows.Count to a specific worksheet.

Comment: Yes, sure. Thanks @braX

Comment: @adhywijaya I would like to change it to row 5. But there it defines range (A)

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to find the last row first

```
lLastRow = Worksheets("Evaluation").Cells(Worksheets("Evaluation").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

and then your destination range will look like this

```
.Range("A" & lLastRow + 1)
```